# Is this relation an Equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

> {(A,B) : A, B ⊆ X, there is a bijective f : A → B}, X is limited.

I have to show if this is (for proving that's an equivalence relation):

 $R ⊆ X \times X$

I) reflexive (if $∀x ∈ X : (x, x) ∈ R$)

II) symmetrical (if $∀x,x' ∈ X : (x, x') ∈ R ⇒  (x,x') ∈ R$)

III) transitive (if $∀x, x', x'' ∈ R : (x, x') ∈ R (x',x'') ∈ R ⇒ (x, x'') ∈ R$)

Alright, I understand what and how I have to do it, but somehow not with this task.

Maybe someone could show me how to transform the very first line into something I can work on.
I'm also a little confused about that $R⊆X \times X$ thing. It's A, B ⊆ X and I'm afraid that my 3 points I have to show can't be applied that easily on my task.

Comment: The relation is on the set of subsets of $X$, in fact it is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)\times\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Comment: @egreg So would it be R ⊆ A x B in this case?

Comment: No, $R\subseteq\mathcal P(X)\times\mathcal P(X)$, and if $A,B\subseteq X$ (that is, $A,B\in\mathcal P(X)$), then $(A,B)$ might be an element of $R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular relation $R$, we have *two* base sets, one is $X$, its *subsets* are the 'elements' among which $R$ is interpreted, so the base set of $R$ now is the power set $\mathcal P(X)$, that is, $R\subseteq \mathcal P(X)\times\mathcal P(X)$.

You need to show that, for all $A,B,C\in\mathcal P(X)$:

1. $(A,A)\in R$, i.e. there is a bijection $A\to A$.
2. If there is a bijection $A\to B$, then there is one $B\to A$.
3. If there are bijections $A\to B$ and $B\to C$, then there is one $A\to C$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it now as I am sure I understand everything I need to continue.

Comment: Sets as $A=\{1,2\}$ to show '*something like this*'.. What do you mean?

Comment: Doesn't matter now, I thought I had to show it by an example of numbers, but it was my mistake thinking this. Thanks anyway. :)